# Rust TcpListener does not response outside request

Tags: tcp, rust

My main function is this:

```
fn main() {
let listener = TcpListener::bind("192.168.1.187:9527").unwrap();
println!("Listening for connections on port {}", 9527);
for stream in listener.incoming() {
    match stream {
        Ok(stream) => {
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let req_stream = &stream.try_clone().unwrap();
                let req = request::new(req_stream);
                let res = response::new(stream.try_clone().unwrap());
                handle_client(req, res)
            });
        }
        Err(e) => println!("Unable to connect: {}", e),
    }
}
}
```

I can get response through `127.0.0.1:9527` but I can't get response from `192.168.1.187:9527` which is my public ip in my office, even doing this on the computer that server is deployed.

Does rust `TcpListener` only work on localhost? How can I make it accept outside requests?

Comment: Is the connection timing out?

Comment: Could it be a firewall on your machine blocking incoming requests?

Comment: @Prabhu It says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @Lukazoid I use archlinux, I don't recall install any firewall, besides, another node.js serve listening port 4001 works perfectly.

Comment: Can you do `ss -lnp` and see the bindings ?

Comment: I ran `ss -lnp | grep 9527`, it says 
`tcp    LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:9527                  *:*                   users:(("servo",pid=2163,fd=3))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ss -lnp` is indicating that the server is bound only to loop back address - 127.0.0.1. And hence the client receiving RST in trying to connect at `192.168.1.187:9527`.

Try:

`TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:9527").unwrap();`

This shall bind to all interfaces available in the system.

Not sure why "192.168.1.187" didn't work. But lets try "0.0.0.0" and see `ss` output.

Comment: `tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:9527                  *:*                   users:(("servo",pid=2228,fd=3))
` and this solves the issue. Also wonder why `127.0.0.1` doesn't work... Thanks for helping~